# Можно ли разместить процесс-сервер и процесс клиент, взаимодействующие через shared memory, в одном решении?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, inter-process

Если я хочу написать в Visual Studio 2019 Comminity в Win32 API на C++ процесс-сервер и процесс клиент, взаимодействующие друг с другом через общую область памяти (shared memory), и, представляющие собой два отдельных приложения (консольное приложение C++ - сервер и оконное приложение Win32 - клиент), то могу ли я, в этом случае, разместить их как два проекта в одном решении или же придётся создавать отдельные решения для каждого из этих процессов? Подскажите, пожалуйста. До этого не занимался взаимодействием процессов.

Comment: Их можно разместить в одном solution. Взаимодействие процессов на это не влияет.

Comment: Спасибо, @nevilad. Но мне как новичку пока не понятно ещё одно: как они будут находить друг-друга будучи отдельными приложениями? Я смотрел другие исходники по этой теме и всё равно пока не понятно. Можете пояснить?

Comment: Для разных способов взаимодействия поиск будет разным. Для shared memory область как правило делают именованной. Сервер создает ее с заданным именем, клиент по известному имени открывает.

Comment: Спасибо большое, @nevilad. То есть получается, что имя, присвоенное приложением-сервером области этой "разделяемой" памяти, которую он создал, становится "видным" из приложения-клиента, вне зависимости от того, находятся ли клиент и сервер в разных решениях или в одном. Так?

Comment: Да. Решение не влияет на работу приложений.